# AJAX Posts multiple times in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

http://cl.ly/2D221O0J33421Y1v2V0Q

Is there any way to avoid this?

Works perfectly in Firefox, etc.

`votes.php:` http://pastie.org/1369778

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("a.vote_down").click(function(){
 //get the id
 the_id = $(this).attr('id');

 // show the spinner
 $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");

 //the main ajax request
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: "action=vote_down&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
   url: "/votes.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn(1000);
    $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: is that the issue whats been posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried having your click handler `return false;` (placed at the end of the function, of course)? Or, try taking an argument in on that handler called `e`, and add e.stopPropagation();

Bottom line is, you wanna prevent the click event from bubbling once you've handled it.

Comment: Is it possible to add a snippet of HTML that goes with this script so I can see if the markup has something to do with it, and try to reproduce myself?

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  If you'd like?

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you provide the HTML that goes with this script. I don't see anything wrong with your code, so I'm interested to see if there's something in the markup, and if nothing else, I can try and reproduce it on my end.

Comment: Sorry, realized you must be logged in to do it. One sec. lemme paste it up: http://pastie.org/1371737

Comment: I think the code works, but your outputting of comments and applying voting behaviors has problems. You are emitting the script (ala http://pastie.org/1371658) after each comment, as if the script was constrained to each comment. However, your comment will attach the same click handler to ALL vote_up/vote_down links, meaning if you have 2 comments, your vote up/down will be submitted twice, or if you have 100 comments, they'll be submitted 100 times. You should emit the voting code ONCE after the comments are emitted. Does that make sense?

Comment: That definitely makes sense.  I tried to do $("a.vote_down#the_id") but that doesn't work. Is it possible to leave the ID untouched and still do that?

Comment: I think there are a few ways to do that, but one that would work is $('a.vote_down').filter('#the_id').click(...);

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

if it is href event do the following at the end of the code

`event.preventDefault();` // this is better way of doing

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

or

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "delegate" method instead of the "click" shortcut. The "$.delegate" prevents event "bubbling" by assigning the event to the context of the element instead of the window object.

Also, if you are you using an "anchor" with an empty "href" parameter, you could try to use another HTML element, like a span.